# Belgian Visa on hold. What does this mean?

Tags: schengen-visas, application-status

I submitted my visa application on 13th November and my visa status is "on hold" it  has been one month and two weeks!!! No one is telling me anything. What should i do?

Comment: While the other question is technically a duplicate, it was a scenario of only 3 days while this one is well over a month. Now the past two weeks had major holidays, but that wouldn't necessarily account for the entire delay.